# How to setup jetty server properly after jakarta migration

Tags: java, jetty, cxf, jakarta-migration

Here is my CXF web service application. When I upgraded javax to jakarta here shows the change and exception.

> cxfVersion=4.0.2
>
> slf4jVersion=2.0.7
>
> org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:4.0.2
>
> org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:11.0.15
>
> org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain:jetty-jakarta-servlet-api:5.0.2

```
public void Server startServer(WebServiceClientFactory<Order> webServiceClientFactory,
                                  TokenAuthorizer tokenAuthorizer) {
    initResources(webServiceClientFactory);
    CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet cxf = new CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet();
    ServletHolder servlet = new ServletHolder(cxf);
    servlet.setInitParameter("jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application", MainApplication.class.getName());
    servlet.setInitOrder(1);
    servlet.setName("services");
    servlet.setForcedPath("services");
    ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler();
    handler.addServlet(servlet, "/*");
    Server jetty = JettyUtils.getJetty(clientFactory.getCertificateClient(), ConfigUtils.CONFIG);
    jetty.setHandler(handler);
    jetty.start();
}
```

And the expception now I'm getting is showing below

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: At least one resource class should be specified
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.getServiceClasses(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:304)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.init(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$2(ServletHandler.java:725)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
```

Comment: Did you upgrade Jetty as well? I don't know if you need at least version 10 or 11; I've used 11 successfully in one of my  projects.

Comment: Thanks Rob, yes it is 11.0.5 jetty servlet